# How AJAX calls work with TWIG

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twig

I am trying to understand how Twig can load a template through AJAX.
From their website, it is clear how to load a template (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html)

```
echo $twig->render('index.html', array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

But how would this work for an AJAX call?  How would you tell Twig that you want to 'render' something that is only a part of index.html ... and not reload the entire page?  I looked at Twig's sole Ajax example (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html), but this doesn't explain how Twig knows what part of the page you want to change.  Assuming your Ajax call results in page content updates.  I just need a simple example of this, something more than what is on Twig's recipe page.

Comment: It doesn't know.  If you want to update a chunk of the page, then only render the chunk that needs to be updated.  This is sometimes called a "partial".

Comment: Do you have an example you could point me to?

Comment: Code, no.  Procedure, yes.  Segment your main template into things that can be [included](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html).  You can independently render them for ajax requests, and just include them inline on the main page.  In theory.  It's been a while since I worked with Twig last, which is why I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: Twig just parses templates, it by itself does not load templates dynamically through ajax. For that you'd probably want to use javascript ajax and load a remote script that provides the includable twig template (parsed and ready).

Otherwise use include or extends to create templates that work together, however these are not loaded via ajax.

Comment: I think I follow with the 'include'.  So, the include takes care of re-rendering that same div(ok, template) over and over?  Like if a user clicks a button every now and then on the same page, the div would be refreshed each time, and not appended to, correct?

Comment: This part depends of what you do after your ajax request. I edit my answer with an example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish that :

1) Separate your index.html in several files like index.html and content.html.
Then use [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) function in index.html to include content.html.

Example :

```
if(isAjaxRequest()) //try to find the right function here
   echo $twig->render('content.html', array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'))
else
   echo $twig->render('index.html', array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

**Edit :**
If you do your ajax request with jQuery for example :

```
$.get('yoururl', function(data) {
  $('#divtoremplace').html(data);
});
```

2) Use the `request.ajax` boolean in your index.html

```
{% if request.ajax == false %}
<p>My header,  not reloaded with ajax</p>
{% endif %}

<p>My content, reloaded with ajax</p>

{% if request.ajax == false %}
<p>Other content,  not reloaded with ajax</p>
{% endif %}
```

Not sure about the second one, but this should do the trick accordind to the documentation. The best way is the first solution, separate your code.

Comment: I tried using request.ajax and Twig threw an error that it does not exist, so I have to generate that on the server side, correct?  It isn't a twig global variable.

Comment: How would you pass isAjaxRequest() or a variable to Twig template?

Answer (score 12):

Directly in the template:

```
{% if app.request.isXmlHttpRequest() %}
  // code if ajax request
{% else %}
  // code if not ajax request
{% endif %}
```