# Render template into Symfony2 with ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have a action in my controller for the index route

routing.yml

```
index:
pattern: /index
defaults: { _controller:AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index }
```

Controller for this path

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Plugin:index.html.twig');
}
```

And the index.html.twig template

```
{% extends'::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' output='css/*.css'
            'bundles/acmedemo/css/*'  %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block body %}
<br>
<div class="container">

<div class="wp_attachment_holder">

    <div class="imgedit-response" id="imgedit-response-8"></div>

    <div class="wp_attachment_image" id="media-head-8">
        <p id="thumbnail-head-8"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/121-1024x583.jpeg" style="max-width:100%" alt=""></p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="edik-wp-extended-edit">Редактировать</a> <span class="spinner"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none" class="image-editor" id="image-editor-8">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
<img class="thumbnail"  data-attach-id="8" data-src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/121-1024x583.jpeg" style="max-width:100%" alt="">
    <script>
            $('#edik-wp-extended-edit').click(function() {
                window.location= Routing.generate('ajax');
//                $('#output').load('/ajax/index');
            });
        </script>
    </div>
{% endblock %}`
```

When the button Редактировать is clicked i want to load another template with ajax.

another.html.twig

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

routing.yml

```
ajax:
pattern: /ajax/index
defaults: { _controller :AcmeDemoBundle:Default:ajax }
options:
    expose: true
```

Controller for this path

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
    $template = $this->renderView('AcmeDemoBundle:Plugin:another.html.twig');
    return new Response($template);
}
```

But when i click the button my uri will be `/ajax/index`. What i want is that it stays by `/index` and the template will be rendered into my index template

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: For me this answer is the best http://stackoverflow.com/a/23209195/2008111

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, your `ajaxAction()` should be a bit different as far as I know.

For me this works:

```
    $template = $this->forward('AcmeDemoBundle:Plugin:another.html.twig')->getContent();

    $json = json_encode($template);
    $response = new Response($json, 200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
```

The `forward()` function renders the template and returns the rendered HTML code.

Your JavaScript file should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: Routing.generate('ajax'),
    async: false //you won't need that if nothing in your following code is dependend of the result
})
.done(function(response){
    template = response;
    $('#your_div').html(template.html); //Change the html of the div with the id = "your_div"                        
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
});
```

You make an AJAX call to the your `ajaxAction`, which will return the HTML of the template you want to be rendered.

After that you just need to add a `<div id="your_div"></div>` at the position you want the template to be rendered. This workes perfectly for me.

To mention is that you need to break down the `ajax` template to just the code that should be shown.

Comment: So, a changed my ajaxAction() in my controller and put your js code into block `<script></script>`? after that i pressed button, but nothing do.
Sorry, my english so bad.
Best regards, Vlad

Comment: You need to add the ajax call, the second codeblock from my answer, to your `click()` function for the button. So the code will run when the button was clicked. Also you need to add a `<div></div>` with a id you want. I took the `your_id` as example. Keep in mind to change the id in the div AND the JavaScript code, then it should work.

Comment: @KhorneHoly where the **Routing** from url parameter come from ?

Comment: @bedomon This comes from the JMSI18nRoutingBundle for Symfony2, which generates you the paths for actions dynamically in JavaScript. Routing.generate('ajax') means that the url should be the on the fly generated path for the controller action with the path name "ajax"

Comment: @KhorneHoly thanks, I've just see the FOSJsRoutingBundle who have the same function **Routing.generate**

Answer (score -1):

Please try generate ajax route like this

```
window.location= '{{ path("ajax") }}';
```

Added:

For make ajax request change windows.location to ajax request

```
$( "#output" ).load( '{{ path("ajax") }}', function() {
  alert('Load done');
});
```

Added explanation of use:

js code will work only if you put it on Twig template. If you put it to js file it will not work. 
In case of original questions.

```
<div id="output"></div>
<img class="thumbnail"  data-attach-id="8" data-src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/121-1024x583.jpeg" style="max-width:100%" alt="">
<script>
      $('#edik-wp-extended-edit').click(function() {
            $( "#output" ).load('{{ path("ajax") }}');
      });
</script>
```

You can use something like FOSJsRoutingBundle to proper use SF2 routing in js

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help me.
When i press button browser redirect and uri is `/ajax/index`

Comment: Yes this is behavior that you write. You write "window.location= " that mean redirect, not ajax action.

Comment: If you question related to how to make ajax request to load page, please change header. Now it misunderstand.

Comment: This will never work. You can't mixin JavaScript with Twig like this because the Twig will be rendered way before the JavaScript even knows it exists itself

Comment: @KhorneHoly can you please provide more details why it not wored? Not clear for me. Yes this is not correct way using twig together with js but from my view it should work correct. During render template {{ path(..) }} will converted to string route. So as result on html page we have something like $("#output").load("/ajax/load"); Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you write the twig in the template. But Twig === PHP. PHP will be rendered on the Server and the results will be send to the client. Yeah, you're also sending JavaScript to, but only the source files. The server does not touch them. Only the user Browser does that. So the Browser keeps on working down the JavaScript until the line with the Twig and has no clue of it. It has no idea what Twig is, even what PHP is. The Browser does not know about that. But because PHP is serverside and JS will be compiled on the Browser the TWIG won't be touched but sent as a string.

Comment: @KhorneHoly that you for detailed explanation. I expect that code I provide will be write on twig template not in js. Of course insert twig into js will not work. Add explanation to answer.